# Describing the algebra representations of the Laurent polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be your favorite field. The "Laurent polynomials" in one variable is the commutative polynomial algebra $k[x,x^{-1}]$ in the two variables $x$ and $x^{-1}$ together with the obvious relation $x.x^{-1} = 1$. Where can I find a decsription of the representations of this algebra?

Edit: By a representation I mean a linear map from $k[x,x^{-1}]$ to the matrices on a finite-dim $k$-vector space (where multiplication is composition of linear maps).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add the [tag:reference-request] to your question.

Comment: @Jose: Ok - it has been done!

Comment: Another formulation is that you are looking for the (finite-dimensional) linear representations of the group $\mathbb{Z}$. Such a representation is just the data of a vector space $V$ and an automorphism of $V$ (the image of $x$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Captain Lama's comments :

$k[x,x^{-1}]$ is canonically isomorphic to the group algebra $k[\mathbb{Z}]$. Indeed, we have a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\mapsto k[x,x^{-1}]$ sending $1$ to $x$, which induces a $k$-algebra morphism $k[\mathbb{Z}]\to k[x,x^{-1}]$, which is easily seen to be an isomorphism.

Now, for any group $G$, the set of $k$-algebra representations $k[G]\to End(V)$ is canonically isomorphic to the set of (finite dimensional) linear representations $G\to GL(V)$.

Indeed, if we have a linear representation $G\to GL(V)\subset End(V)$, it extends to a $k$-algebra morphism $k[G]\to End(V)$ .

Conversely, since $G\subset k[G]^\times$, a  $k$-algebra morphism $k[G]\to End(V)$ restricts to a group morphism $G\to End(V)^\times=GL(V)$. Both constructions are mutally inverse.

Hence for $G=\mathbb{Z}$, it is enough to compute $Hom_{grps}(\mathbb{Z},GL(V))$, which is canonically isomorphic to $GL(V)$, since a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any group is uniquely determined by the image of $1$.

Note that two representations $V$, $V'$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ will be equivalent if and only if the corresponding automorphisms $u,u'$ are conjugate (by an isomorphism $V\overset{\sim}{\to} V'$).

So, if you keep track of all identifications, you will end up with the following description: all the representations $k[x,x^{-1}]\to End(V)$ have the form $\rho_{u}:k[x,x^{-1}]\to GL(V)$, where $u\in GL(V)$ and $\rho_u(\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} a_m x^m)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}a_mu^m$ (where the $a_m'$ s are all zero except for a finite number of them).

Moreover, equivalence  classes of algebra representations corresponds to similitary classes of automorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Does that mean that each finite-dim $V$ breaks up into a direct sum of $1$-dim sub-irreps?

Comment: No. Not every $u$ is diagonalizable...

Comment: Yes, of course - good point.

Comment: So more generally, for any finitely generated torsion-free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^n$, the linear representations will look like this? I mean to say, we would have $n$ commuting matrices and a map from each $1_k$ to the $k$-th generator?